# key listener not working while using laptop keyboard

Tags: java

ive created a key listener but apparently it doesnt work,im using a laptop keyboard is that a problem?

```
public class Subscript extends Applet implements KeyListener {

    public String number;
    public void init() {

        this.addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)  {

        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {

            System.out.println("hi");
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I expect the result should be hi in console but it doesnt show up when I press up button

Comment: Break in `keyPressed` and see what the keycode actually is.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded and ran your code and it seems to work perfectly. The problems I believe you are having is the applet is not focused on your screen. If you click on the applet with your mouse before you attempt to hit the up arrow the program should work.